# Can anyone help me to create a bowling pic via ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a project about a bowling game via using the THREE.JS library

I need to convert this code into a pin

```
const STONE_HEIGHT = 15;
const STONE_RADIUS = 1;

makeStone(radius, mainCol, teamColor) {
  // Définitions des grandeurs
  let stoneHeightMiddle = STONE_HEIGHT * 0.3;
  let baseRadius = STONE_RADIUS * 1;
  let handleRadius = STONE_RADIUS / 100;
  let verticalCylinderLength = STONE_RADIUS / 4;
  let cylinderSpacing = verticalCylinderLength / 2;
  let baseHeight = STONE_HEIGHT / 2;
  let horizontalCylinderLength = STONE_RADIUS - (2 * handleRadius) - cylinderSpacing;

  // Création de la pierre en elle-même
  var A, B, C, D;
  var bezSup, bezInf, bezCent;
  var latheSup, latheInf, latheCent;
  var mainMaterial, teamMaterial;

  mainMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: mainCol,
    flatShading: false,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });
  teamMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: teamColor,
    flatShading: false,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });

  A = new THREE.Vector2(0, STONE_HEIGHT / 2);
  B = new THREE.Vector2(radius, stoneHeightMiddle / 2);
  C = new THREE.Vector2(radius, -stoneHeightMiddle / 2);
  D = new THREE.Vector2(0, -STONE_HEIGHT / 2);
}
```

I'm trying to convert this code ( it's like a stone) to a bowling pin

Comment: What you're looking for [is called `LatheGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/LatheGeometry). You have to create an array of 2D points that defines the contour, then it rotates this contour along the Y-axis to create a mesh like a vase.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37107107/1461008